# JS Breakpoint doesn't get hit, but code executes

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I have an unsual problem and working on it since hours. My breakpoint doesn't get hit within the function yet the functionality works, it is driving me crazy.  I have tried this with both Chrome/developer tools and Firefox/Firebug. I never had something like this before.

The first breakpoint hits when I click on the button New Conversation.
But then when I click on Cancel Button that comes through the jquery .load() the break point doesn't hit. Yet the functionality behind it executes (the div gets emptied).

What am I missing please?

```
function cancel_new_conversation(event){
    //2nd Breakppoint below this line doesn't get hit, but the empty() statement works.
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#new_conversation_div').empty();
}

function new_conversation(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href") + "/";
    $('#new_conversation_div').load(url, function(){
       //1st Breakpoint gets hit.               
       $('#new_conversation_cancel_button').click(cancel_new_conversation);     
    }); 
}

$(document).ready(function (){      
  $('#new_conversation_button').click(new_conversation);
}
```

Is there anything I am doing that breaks the javascript somehow?

EDIT:

Good idea with the alerts. here is the proof. Maybe its an environment issue? I have to try it on a different machine.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you have an alert in the functions, just to check whether it is a debugger / code executed issue?

Comment: My suspicion would be that you have more than one copy of this code, and the breakpoint is on a copy that isn't being run. I'd try adding a `debugger;` statement to the code you think is running, clearing cache, and running it again -- both so you can see if the source you're looking at gets updated (you see the `debugger;` statement) and so that if it's not, the `debugger;` statement stops the code where it *is* running. That doesn't help you if you're editing the code you're looking at, sadly, but...

Comment: Did you set the breakpoint in jQuery empty(), just to see from the callstack whether the second empty is triggered from your function?

Comment: Does the second breakpoint (the bad one) get hit when you remove the first (good) one?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have double checked, even on my PC it is the same problem. It doesn't seem like a copy of the code, because whatever I change in Aptana STudio I do see it reflected in the bowser upon reloading. 
jakub, if I deactivate the 1st breakpoint, nothing happens either. The second never breaks.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the leads and advice. I finally found the problem. hope the answer helps someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lunch yesterday in my infinite wisdom I had my partial html that I was meant to load with `$('#new_conversation_div').load(url, function()` designed as a full blown html with header and body.

Hence once it was loaded into my div, the html markup became completely a mess (two headers, two bodies)

I moved the javascript file from the corrupted partial html into my main html and removed the header and body from the partial html. Now that I .load() the partial html, it all works as expected and the breakpoint hits. It was very hard to find.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem i can see in your code is that you don't unbind click event on #new_conversation_cancel_button when loading a new conversation.
If you use jquery >1.7, you should test following code:

```
function cancel_new_conversation(event){
    //2nd Breakppoint below this line doesn't get hit, but the empty() statement works.
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("cancel_new_conversation");
    $('#new_conversation_div').empty();
}

function new_conversation(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href") + "/";
    $('#new_conversation_div').load(url, function(){
       //1st Breakpoint gets hit.               
       $('#new_conversation_cancel_button').off('click').on('click',cancel_new_conversation);     
    }); 
}
$(document).ready(function (){      
  $('#new_conversation_button').on('click',new_conversation);
});

​
```